# graphviz - fixed node positions

Tags: graphviz, css-position

I have a graph that is processed by neato and I'm adding new edges to it. However, I don't want that the old nodes to be moved. I want that neato computes the new positions of the new nodes and the old nodes stay in the same place.

```
strict graph {
    node0 [pos="1,2"];
    node1 [pos="2,3"];
}
```

and I add new edges:

```
strict graph {
    node0 [pos="1,2"];
    node1 [pos="2,3"];
    node1 -- node2 [len="3"];
    ...
}
```

I want to get the same positions on the old nodes. For example:

```
strict graph {
    node0 [pos="1,2"];
    node1 [pos="2,3"];
    node2 [pos="3,4"];
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 16):

You can pin a node's position by setting the [node attribute `pin=true`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pin).

Or put a '!' at the end of the pos attribute: `pos="34,12!"`

Comment: `$ cat g.dot
strict graph {
 node0 [pos="2363.2,13230!"];
 node1 [pos="2452.2,1335!"];
 node1 -- node2 [len="9.4"];            
}`

and running neato: `$ neato g.dot 
strict graph {
 node [label="\N"];
 graph [bb="0,0,71043,8.9511e+05"];
 node0 [pos="64603,8.9509e+05", width="0.9027", height="0.5"];
 node1 [pos="71011,38647", width="0.89579", height="0.5"];
 node2 [pos="32.249,18", width="0.89579", height="0.5"];
 node1 -- node2 [len="9.4", pos="70988,38634 69544,37849 1500.7,817.18 55.599,30.708"];
}` it gives very strange numbers

Comment: Yay! The '!' version works through pygraphviz too. The pin=true version crashes neato (when set through pygraphviz).

Answer (score 1):

Running it with -n option should do the trick.

Comment: this really works, but be aware that it works only with `neato`.