# Graphviz family tree with fixed nodes

Tags: graphviz

I just had the idea to overlay a family tree over a table plan such that guests of my event can see where other family members sit. I have the table plan as pdf file. Would it be possible to fix the positions of the nodes such that they coincide with the persons seat and to let graphviz optimize the routing of the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly fix the node positions (using the `pos` attribute with `!` or the node attribute `pin=true` -- see the answer to [graphviz - fixed node positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309201/graphviz-fixed-node-positions), which appears to be by one of the GraphViz team members, however the edge routing might require some aesthetic help.

For example, given `familytree.dot`:

```
digraph G {
    node [ shape="plaintext" ]
    graph [ splines="ortho" ]
    dad -> parents 
    mom -> parents
    parents -> son1
    parents -> son2
    parents -> daughter1
    parents -> daughter2
    granddad -> dad
    granddad [pos = "0,2!"]
    dad [pos = "0,4!"]
    mom [pos = "0,6!"]
    son1 [pos = "2,2!"]
    son2 [pos = "2,4!"]
    daughter1 [pos = "2,6!"]
    daughter2 [pos = "2,8!"]
}
```

... running `neato -Tpng -ofamilytree.png familytree.dot` gives the following result:

[image]