# Overlay graph with graphviz neato/fdp

Tags: graphviz, dot, neato

How do I add an edge to a graphviz neato/fdp graph, that has no influence of the layout. I tried especially `weight=0` and `w=0` as stated in the documentation, and many other combination with the `len` attribute and different `weight`s .

I'm aming for a map of nodes with "fixed" position/neighborhood and an overlay of additional relations.

Answer (score 1):

This should be achievable by a two-step approach where you first run graphviz with the nodes and subset of edges you want it to use to compute positions and have it output the node positions (for example, use the -Tdot output). Then add the additional edges and rerun graphviz again.
You may need to `pin` the nodes, see this question: [graphviz - fixed node positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309201/graphviz-fixed-node-positions)

Comment: I generate the dor via a script any way, so this should be possible, but i doubt that there is no direct solution. I think this is a common issue?